# YouTube google event

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Has anyone managed to get the tracking of embedded YouTube video play/pause/ended working with the Monster Insights plugin for WordPress, or have an example where they have this working with Google universal.js? Please see below for the code I have so far. I have other GA Events being tracked successfully which are working fine, e.g. onclick="__gaTracker ('send', 'event', 'Mobile Call Button', 'call', 'mobile-call-button');"

```
<script>

// YouTube API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_...";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// This code is called by the YouTube API to create the player object

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(event) {

player = new YT.Player('decisions', {

events: {

'onReady': onPlayerReady,

'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange

}

});

}

var pauseFlag = false;

function onPlayerReady(event) {

// do nothing, no tracking needed

}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

// track when user clicks to Play

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Play', 'decisionsvideo');

pauseFlag = true;

}

// track when user clicks to Pause

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED && pauseFlag) {

__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Pause', 'decisionsvideo');

pauseFlag = false;

}

// track when video ends

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Finished', 'decisionsvideo');

}

}

</script>
```